# как работает setSelector()?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть код:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку, появляется список всех приложений, которые отображаются в лаунчере. Насколько я понимаю при помощи `setSelector(Intent)` мы можем выбрать элемент при помощи кода. Я хочу выбрать приложение,которое может отправить простой текст. Я добавляю следующие строчки:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    Intent ii = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    ii.setType("text/plain");
    i.setSelector(ii);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Но я почему-то получаю exception.

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] sel=act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain} }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2117)
...
```

**Правильно ли я понимаю суть `setSelector(Intent)`? Если да то что я сделал не так?**

Comment: отправить куда и откуда? у вас мне кажется напутаны немного типы intent и поэтому падает.

Comment: Если вы хотите что-то отправить, запустите непосредственно второй интент. Селектор, насколько возможно понять документацию,  для случая когда вы хотите запустить приложение, которое может отправлять текст, но ничего отправлять на самом деле не нужно, а нужно просто запустить главную активность. Это не для выбора за пользователя, чтобы запустить конкретное приложение нужно максимально уточнить интент под его фильтр или вообще указать его пакет и класс активности.

Comment: @woesss `Селектор, насколько возможно понять документацию, для случая когда вы хотите запустить приложение, которое может отправлять текст, но ничего отправлять на самом деле не нужно, а нужно просто запустить главную активность.` А не могли бы показать пример того как это сделать, а то я как не пытался у меня результат одни - exception

Comment: @Andrew я просто пытаюсь понять как работает `setSelector()` и для чего он нужен

Answer (score 0):

setSelection нужен  для выбора элемента .работает вот так mySpinner.setSelection(position);

Comment: эм... а спиннер тут-то при чем? речь об intent идёт вроде